# How to move the scrollbar down

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar, positioning

So I have a scrollbar that I have styled using CSS.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar
{
width: 12px;
background-color: #F5F5F5;
padding-top: 60px; /*doesn't work*/
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
background-color: #555;
}
```

Unfortunately the 'padding-top: 60px;' doesn't work. Is it possible to move it down 60px? If so how would I go about doing this? Thanks! :)

Edit: Ascii image to explain what I want to happen.

```
_____________________
|       60px gap -> _|
|                  | |
|                  |||
|__________________|_|
```

Comment: Why do u need padding top for scroll bar?

Comment: In that top 60 px are you sticking any content or in the beginning itself you want to scroll it down to 60px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a padding to the scroll.
You can use a 'fake' container and make it scrollable, absolute positioned `60px` on top:

```
.wrapper {
   position: absolute; 
   overflow-y:auto;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   top:60px; 
   background:gold;
   padding:20px;
}
```

See the [working demo here](http://jsbin.com/lujurayavi/1/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. I think I found an easy solution.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Or is you need to update it in JavaScript

css

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  margin-top: var(--scrollbar-margin-top, 60px);
}
```

js

```
myElement.style.setProperty('--scrollbar-margin-top', anotherElement.clientHeight + 'px');
```